# Python plantUML diagram renders with odd characters

Tags: python-3.x, uml

I'm using this python code to generate a plantUML diagram:

```
import codecs
import importlib.util
import os
from plantuml import PlantUML
import sadisplay
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox

def create_erd():
    # Get the file with the models.
    modelFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = os.getcwd, title = 'Select models.py file', filetypes = (('python files', '*.py'), ('all files', '*.*')))

    # Import the file as a module.
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('models', modelFile)
    models = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(models)

    # Create a descriptor that lists all the attributes and relationships outlined in the models.py file.
    desc = sadisplay.describe([getattr(models, attr) for attr in dir(models)])

    # Create the plantuml file based on the descriptor.  This is needed to create the png image file
    with codecs.open('schema.plantuml', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(sadisplay.plantuml(desc))

    # Call the plantuml library to take the plantuml file and generate the png file.
    plantuml = PlantUML('http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/img/')
    done = plantuml.processes_file(filename = 'schema.plantuml', outfile = 'schema.png')    

    # Notify the user if the process was successful.
    if done:
        messagebox.showinfo('Create ERD', 'The ERD was successfully written to schema.png.')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Create ERD', 'The ERD was not successfully generated.')
```

The generated plantuml file looks like this:

```
@startuml

skinparam defaultFontName Courier

Class Department {
    INTEGER ★ id     
    VARCHAR ⚪ name   
    +       employees
}

Class Employee {
    INTEGER  ★ id           
    INTEGER  ☆ department_id
    INTEGER  ☆ role_id      
    DATETIME ⚪ hired_on     
    VARCHAR  ⚪ name         
    +        department     
    +        role           
}

Class Role {
    INTEGER ★ role_id
    VARCHAR ⚪ name   
    +       roles    
}

Employee <--o Department: department_id

Employee <--o Role: role_id

right footer generated by sadisplay v0.4.9

@enduml
```

But the output looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure why the image renders this way and therefore don't know how to fix it or if it can be fixed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reading in the uml file and replacing the characters:

```
processThis = uml.read().replace('â˜…', '[PK]').replace('â˜†', '[FK]').replace('âšª', '    ')
```

That worked out.

Comment: We never should have left the room of ASCII. Unicode is the hell...